# What does this symbol mean for the MLE method?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

This is an implementation of the maximum likelihood method on $\hat \pi$. 
I am unsure what that $\mathbf 1$ looking symbol means.

> MLE estimate of $\pi_y$ is
>   $$\hat\pi_y:\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf 1\{y_i = y\}.$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g2bE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an indicator random variable.
It means
$$\mathbf 1\{y_i = y\} = \begin{cases} 1,&\text{if } y_i = y\\0,&\text{if } y_i\neq y\end{cases}$$